# Why doesn't windows 10 ssh-keygen honor the -m option?

Tags: windows-10, public-key-encryption, ssh-keygen

Windows 10 command line `ssh-keygen -b 2048 -mPKCS8` doesn't change the `.pub` file created to PKCS8 (it's always the one-liner).

I can do this to get the actual format output to the screen:
`ssh-keygen -ef test.key -mPKCS8`

but if I tell it to use `PKCS8` when generating, it seems to ignore it?

Is this as intended or a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The `id_{alg}.pub` files are ALWAYS (not just on Windows) OpenSSH format (i.e. one line); if you manually make it any other format `ssh` won't work. `-m` on a generate or update command affects the _privatekey_ file not the publickey; on export `-e` (only) it can format the publickey in what OpenSSH incorrectly calls PKCS8 but is in fact X.509/PKIX SPKI and NOT PKCS8. @Ramhound: actually OpenSSH 9.6 now _does_ support PKCS8 for ed25519 privatekey, but this question (1) isn't about ed25519 and (2) isn't about privatekey.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Author isn’t using that version as the built-in version of OpenSSH hasn’t yet reach the 9.x branch